# Jquery coloring table cells according to condition and values

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Trying to colour table rows that contain **years<= 2004** in the second column and the third column should have value **"Ne"**. What I am getting now is colored rows that contain only values in the third column **"Ne"** and condition years<=2005 is ignored. Is there some way to write condition using **&&**, or my syntax is bad?

```
$(function(){
        $("#randa").click(function(){
          $("#lentele td:nth-child(2)").each(function()
          {
            if (parseInt($(this).text()) <=2005)
            {
              
              $("#lentele td:nth-child(3)").each(function()
              {
                if ($(this).text() == "Ne")
                {
                  $(this).parent("tr").addClass('spalvinti');
                  
                }

                
              }
              
            )
            
            }
          })
        })
```

});

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find applicable cell with text `Ne`, it needs to be in the same row as the matching cell with the year. The code with problem is finding all cells with `Ne` instead.

I would process row by row as below:

```js
$("#randa").click(function(){
  $("#lentele tr").each(function() {
    if (parseInt($(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').text()) <= 2005
        && $(this).children('td:nth-child(3)').text() === 'Ne') {
      $(this).addClass('spalvinti');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
table { border: 1px solid #eee; }
tr.spalvinti { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="randa">
  <table id="lentele">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2010</td><td>Taip</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td><td>1999</td><td>Ne</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td><td>2001</td><td>Ne</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td><td>2004</td><td>Ne</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td><td>2008</td><td>Ne</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```